# What is the origin of Black knight satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, nasa, astrobiology, exoplanet

Is it true that an extraterrestrial satellite orbits earth in retrograde? If the Black knight exists, can we presume that it is placed there by aliens who are technologically  more advanced than humans? Did they place it there to keep an eye on human activities and advancements? Also why would some space agencies  hide it's presence (if they are actually trying to hide)?

Comment: [Black Knight satellite **conspiracy theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Knight_satellite_conspiracy_theory)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site, perhaps [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). See their meta: [Are conspiracy theory based questions allowed here?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3983)

Comment: Down vote for unsubstantiated "why would some space agencies like NASA hide it's presence?" and for *making me feel silly* for googling "black knight satellite" ;-)

Comment: A possibly useful data point here is that multiple organizations track objects in orbit including commercial (paid to provide collision avoidance information) and amateur (looking for interesting things), all of whom would have to lie for no good reason about something like this - suggest making this question about how many organizations would notice a retrogade ET object or how small an object would have to be to escape the non government organisations.

Comment: Seeing as the existence of the elusive white knight satellite has yet to be proven as well, the black knight satellite could not feasibly exist, as it has nobody to battle in the void.

Answer (score 5):

I got curious and read this, it makes plenty of sense to me. http://www.jamesoberg.com/sts88_and-black-knight.pdf

The suggestion is that many of the photos are really of a bit of space debris from STS-88. The author explains that the hype is just that, hype.

- The intense passion to want to believe so badly that this is something alien, clouds any type of logical thinking.
- Imaginative captions attached to ‘space junk’ are so much junk themselves, snares for naïve, imprudent viewers

The discussion is in-depth, but here's an example:

[image]

Comment: thanks uhoh, the credit all goes to you, you did everything.

Comment: not at all! You read the question, treated it seriously, did some research, and found a really interesting link that addresses the question head-on in a serious and thoughtful way. All I did was copy/paste!